# Using an icon on a dialog box window C++ Win32 API

Tags: c++, winapi, api, dialog, icons

I am trying to create a dialog box with an icon at the top like so.

[image: icon dialog]

I am using a resource file to load the icon like so.

```
IDI_ICON1          ICON           ".\\usb.ico"
```

I have tried setting the window icon using the following code.

```
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, (LPARAM)IDI_ICON1);
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)IDI_ICON1);
```

hwnd is the window. As a result, I get a blue circle that looks just like the loading icon for Windows 7 and Vista. I am almost positive the icon is being loaded correctly as when I look at the task bar, my program has that icon representing my program. If you need the code I am using for the dialog window itself, let me know I will post it. I am using mingw32 C++ compiler on Windows 7. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use LoadIcon and pass an icon handle to WM_SETICON.

```
HICON hicon = LoadImageW(GetModuleHandleW(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDI_ICONMAIN), IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR | LR_DEFAULTSIZE);
SendMessageW(hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, hicon);
```

Comment: I tried doing `HICON t = LoadIcon(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
            SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)t);` without much luck. I don't know how far from correct my code is.

Comment: The first parameter to LoadIcon should be the current instance handle. Get it by calling GetModuleHandle( NULL ).

Answer (score 5):

I had to cast the return value of `LoadImageW()` to `HICON` , to avoid the error :

> "
>   a value of type "HANDLE" cannot be assigned to an entity of
>   type "HICON"  ...."

this worked for me :

```
.... 
//hDlg is the handle to my dialog window
case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        HICON hIcon;

        hIcon = (HICON)LoadImageW(GetModuleHandleW(NULL),
            MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDI_ICON1),
            IMAGE_ICON,
            GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON),
            GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON),
            0);
        if (hIcon)
        {
            SendMessage(hDlg, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, (LPARAM)hIcon);
        }
    }
    break;
```

and here is the result

[image: win32 Dialog icon]

FYI: the used icon was downloaded from :

http://www.iconsdb.com/orange-icons/stackoverflow-6-icon.html

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's  three years. I would like to add another solution to this. I have tried this on Visual Studio 2017.

`m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
SendMessage(WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)m_hIcon);`