# How do I include a custom icon in the client area of a dialog box?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

This question is different than [Using an icon on a dialog box window C++ Win32 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410846/using-an-icon-on-a-dialog-box-window-c-win32-api), I'm trying to include a custom icon into the **client area** of a dialog box. When I run the code, I get a default Windows icon instead of the custom one I want. If I change the value of `IDI_ICON1` to any number between 80 and 120, I'll get different Windows icons; I've tried higher numbers but then nothing will appear. I saw someone at [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/33736/) run into the same error and I did the same thing, but it didn't make a difference.

[Microsoft's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381017(v=vs.85).aspx) reference about icons.

When I run the code:
[image: Unmatched Dialog Box]

Visual Studio says it'll look like this: 
[image: Visual Studio's Dialog Editor]

Source.cpp

```
#pragma comment(lib,"ole32.lib")
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

_TCHAR szClassName[] = "StackOverflow";
HWND hwnd;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND handle, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam);

int _stdcall WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR CmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    MSG messages;
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;
    HWND about;

    wincl.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wincl.hInstance = hInstance;
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;//COLOR_BACKGROUND;
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wincl))
        return 0;

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LEFT | WS_EX_LTRREADING | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE,     //dwExStyle
        szClassName,                                                            //ClassName
        "StackOverflow",                                                        //WindowName
        WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU | WS_CAPTION | WS_EX_PALETTEWINDOW,          //Window Style
        CW_USEDEFAULT,                                                          //Horizontal Pos
        CW_USEDEFAULT,                                                          //Verticals Pos
        100,                                                                    //Width
        100,                                                                    //Height
        HWND_DESKTOP,                                                           //Parent
        NULL,                                                                   //Menu
        hInstance,                                                              //Module Assoc  
        NULL);                                                                  //CreateStruct

    about = CreateDialog(   NULL,
                            MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG),
                            hwnd,
                            DialogProc);

    while (GetMessage(&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }

    return messages.wParam;
}

INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND handle, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        //This changes the Icon in the TitleBar
        SendMessage(handle, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL,
            (LPARAM)LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1)));
        return TRUE;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(handle);
        return TRUE;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return TRUE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wparam))
        {
        case IDCOK:
            //TODO
        case IDCANCEL:
            //EndDialog(handle,wparam);
            DestroyWindow(handle);
            return TRUE;
        default:
            return FALSE;
        }
    default:
        return FALSE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

StackOverflow.rc

```
#include "resource.h"

IDD_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 245, 57
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_SETFOREGROUND | DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_CENTER | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "About Dialog"
FONT 10, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,166,7,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",2,166,30,50,14
    LTEXT           "The Icon here needs to match the one in the Titlebar",IDC_STATIC,50,15,107,28
    ICON            IDI_ICON1,103,19,16,20,20, SS_ICON
END

// Icon with lowest ID value placed first to ensure application icon
// remains consistent on all systems.
IDI_ICON1               ICON                    "C:\\Users\\pixel\\Desktop\\MEIN.ico"
```

resource.h

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
// Used by StackOverflow.rc
//
#define IDD_DIALOG                      101
#define IDI_ICON1                       103
#define IDCOK                           105
#define IDCANCEL                        106
```

Comment: I assume this is not the icon you wanted?

Comment: @Amadeusz No, I wanted the icon located at `C:\\Users\\pixel\\Desktop\\MEIN.ico`

Comment: Why don't you specify the icon that you want?

Comment: According to the resources you provided (Microsoft) your first argument in the ICON control sholud be text and not an icon resource ID. Maby changing it will help?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] so that people can try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I've updated the question with source code, I tried to be as minimal as possible. I got the sample icon from the [internet](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/60173/example_icon)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your call to `CreateDialog` is not providing a module handle, which is stopping the icon control from being able to locate the specified icon in your program's resources.

Obviously in this instance it defaults to looking in the system image list, which is why you see system icons appear (and change when you change the ID).

Change your call to:

```
about = CreateDialog(hInstance,
                        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG),
                        hwnd,
                        DialogProc);
```

Comment: I've literally spent days on trying to get this to work! I thought that using [CreateDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645434(v=vs.85).aspx) with NULL would work because it says    >If this parameter is NULL, then the current executable is used.    Is there ever a time that I would want to use NULL?

Comment: To be honest I don't know, as you say the docs for `CreateDialog` say that it's valid to pass NULL, it's just that the icon control doesn't like it. Probably best to always pass a valid module handle since it won't hurt and as you see, sometimes helps :)

Comment: It is valid to pass NULL. Especially if you are making a dialog that implements shell-like functionality and you would *want* to use shell32 icons. Sometimes the MSDN documentation is written in a way that implies its more targeting an internal audience. See the documentation for `ShellAbout` for an extreme example.

Comment: I guess this is an additional caveat when [using `NULL` as an `hInstance`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121214-00/?p=5833): if the dialog system just passes the given `hInstance` to `LoadIcon()`, and we know that passing `NULL` to `LoadIcon()` uses the system icon list, then `NULL` isn't always the current module! :D To avoid issues like this, always pass the correct hInstance for your component.